# Why can't I connect my Icecast server to a URL?

Tags: dns, icecast, icecast2

I have an Icecast server serving at the public IP address of my server, e.g. `http://123.456.78.910:8080`. I want users to listen at a URL, `http://stream.mywebsite.com`.

I created an A record to point to my server from `stream.mywebsite.com`, and and added `<hostname>stream.mywebste.com</hostname>` to my icecast.xml file. But, nothing happens. I can still stream from my IP, but not from my URL.

There's virtually no documentation on this. Am I missing a step? I've checked for typos, waited for the domain name to propagate, and had no results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Icecast is listening on port 8080 then you still need to specify that port also with a DNS entry:

`http://stream.mywebsite.com:8080`

If you don't want to specify the port then you need to make Icecast listen to port 80. On most Linux distributions that will require starting icecast as root, BUT specify a change user in the server config.